# Beautiful-Soup / find element only partly?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I tried to read, for example, this link with beautiful soup:
https://sensortower.com/ios/us/ninja-kiwi/app/bloons-td-6/1118115766/overview

I am attempting to scrape this information from the site:
[image]

The html looks like:

```
<div id="app-revenue-downloads" class="shadowed-st content">
    <div class="downloads-revenue-container" data-bind="with: $data.downloadsAndRevenue">
      <a class="downloads-holder" data-bind="
        sense: ['App Intel - Overview - Click Download Estimate', { 'App ID': $parent.appId }],
        attr: { href: $parent.buildStoreIntelUrl('units') },
        click: function() { $parent.switchToStoreIntel('units') },
        tooltip: { animation: false, title: 'View estimates in Store Intelligence', placement: 'bottom' }" href="/store-intel/app-analysis?measure=units&amp;os=ios&amp;country=US&amp;app_id=1118115766" data-original-title="">
        <h3>Downloads</h3>
        <span class="downloads" data-bind="text: $data.downloads">60k</span>
        <span class="downloads-month">
          <span data-bind="text: moment().subtract(1, 'months').subtract(10, 'days').format('MMM YYYY') + ' Worldwide'">Jun 2021 Worldwide</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- ko if: $data.revenue -->
      <a class="revenue-holder" data-bind="
        sense: ['App Intel - Overview - Click Revenue Estimate', { 'App ID': $parent.appId }],
        attr: { href: $parent.buildStoreIntelUrl('revenue') },
        click: function() { $parent.switchToStoreIntel('revenue') },
        tooltip: { animation: false, title: 'View estimates in Store Intelligence (All Revenue is Net)', placement: 'bottom' }" href="/store-intel/app-analysis?measure=revenue&amp;os=ios&amp;country=US&amp;app_id=1118115766" data-original-title="">
        <h3>Revenue</h3>
        <span class="revenue" data-bind="text: $data.revenue">$1m</span>
        <span class="revenue-month">
          <span data-bind="text: moment().subtract(1, 'months').subtract(10, 'days').format('MMM YYYY') + ' Worldwide'">Jun 2021 Worldwide</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

So I'm trying to read at first the element with the id = "app-revenue-downloads" with:

```
tmpElem = soup.find(id="app-revenue-downloads")
print(tmpElem)
```

But for whatever reason I'm only reading the first a-tag (only the a-tag with the class "downloads-holder" but not the a-tag with the class "revenue-holder":

```
<div class="shadowed-st content" id="app-revenue-downloads">
<div class="downloads-revenue-container" data-bind="with: $data.downloadsAndRevenue">
<a class="downloads-holder" data-bind="
        sense: ['App Intel - Overview - Click Download Estimate', { 'App ID': $parent.appId }],
        attr: { href: $parent.buildStoreIntelUrl('units') },
        click: function() { $parent.switchToStoreIntel('units') },
        tooltip: { animation: false, title: 'View estimates in Store Intelligence', placement: 'bottom' }" data-original-title="" href="/store-intel/app-analysis?measure=units&amp;os=ios&amp;country=US&amp;app_id=1574888366">
<h3>Downloads</h3>
<span class="downloads" data-bind="text: $data.downloads">&lt; 5k</span>
<span class="downloads-month">
<span data-bind="text: moment().subtract(1, 'months').subtract(10, 'days').format('MMM YYYY') + ' Worldwide'">Jun 2021 Worldwide</span>
</span>
</a>
<!-- ko if: $data.revenue --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
</div>
```

The driver I initialize with this information:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x800")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')   
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])      
options.add_argument('--headless')
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
if sys.platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
elif sys.platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver'
elif sys.platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)  
driver.get(elem)
driver.set_window_size(1800,1000)
soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Why is Beautiful Soup reading only the first a-tag and not the second one?

Comment: it's Beautiful "Soup", not "Soap". ;-)

Comment: @chitown88 OP might be needing to wash his code ! what the issue lol

Comment: definitely i have to wash my code from time to time... :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = re.findall(r'"(?:downloads|revenue)":"(.+?)"', r.text)
    print(match)


main("https://sensortower.com/ios/us/ninja-kiwi/app/bloons-td-6/1118115766/overview")
```

Output:

```
['60k', '$1m']
```

Comment: It seems to work - thanks a lot. What does this regex command `r'"(?:downloads|revenue)":"(.+?)"'` do at the end? Searching for the first occurence of "downloads" / "revenue"? But does he get the value behind this word?

Comment: @Rapid1898  you welcome. [check-explaination](https://regex101.com/r/Tv9UHx/1)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://sensortower.com/ios/us/ninja-kiwi/app/bloons-td-6/1118115766/overview').text

downloads = re.findall(r'"downloads":"([^"]*)"', r)[0]
revenue = re.findall(r'"revenue":"([^"]*)"', r)[0]

print(downloads, revenue) #60k $1m
```

Comment: You really don't need to use re twice which will loop over `r.text` twice. you can use the `|` `OR` operator which will match the goal within single loop. check my posted answer.